# Type of verb "saying" in a given sentence

Tags: grammar, verbs

let's consider this sentence :

"I've read some posts of users saying that the elephant is greater than the lion."

In a grammar point of view, what the type of "saying" here in the sentence?

And, can I say "users are saying" instead of "users saying" in the sentence?

Comment: You cannot use *I've read some posts of users are saying*. But you could use *I've read some posts of users **who** are saying*.

Comment: @Jason Bassford
Yes, you said it right.
What about the first sentence, is it right?
And what the type of the verb "saying" inside it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that first sentence is right.  "saying" would be a present participle modifying "users" or possibly "posts".

Comment: But the present participle needs a "to be" verb before him, why in this sentence the meaning is complete without writing a "to be" verb?

Comment: This is a participle phrase.  https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/participle_phrases.htm